# How to change folder root when creating a page in Sharepoint Online 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, wiki-pages, sharepoint-library, sitepages

As mentioned in the question title, I would like to find out how do i change the root directory of "create page" function in SharePoint Online 2013? 
Currently, my default root directory is under "/sitepages/.." and would like to use Pages library instead of the Wiki Pages.
And as i understand that Site pages is under the WikiPage library.?

xxmfxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of library that in SP to save pages: "Pages library" and "Site Pages library". "Pages library" is used to save publishing page. "Site Pages library" is used to save wiki page or web part page.

If you do not activate the publishing feature, when you create a new page, the default root directory is under "/sitepages/..".

After you activate the publishing feature, "Pages library" will added to your site. This time when you create a new publishing page, the default root directory is under "/pages/..". When you create a wiki page or a web part page,  the default root directory is under "/sitepages/..".